# viewWithTag can Use limited Time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 UIImageView as Thumbnails with tags: 1, 2, 3.

The following method:

```
- (IBAction)showImage:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  if (sender.view.layer.borderColor != [UIColor redColor].CGColor)
    {
      sender.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
      UIImageView *showFullImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender+10];
      [self.view addSubview:showFullImage];
      showFullImage setTag:sender+20;
      showFullImage.hidden = NO;
    }
  else
    {
      sender.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
      UIImageView *hideFullImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender+20];
      [hideFullImage removeFromSuperView];
      hideFullImage.hidden = YES;
    }
```

So, as you can see, I have 3 `UIImageView` small, thumbnails, with whiteBorderColor.
Also I have created and added to superView another 3 Images Full Size, same frame, and following tags:  11, 12, 13 also those images are hidden.

Now, I use the above code for this idea:

When I touch one of those 3 thumbnails, the borderColor will be red, and the hidden Full Size image which has tag = thumbnail.tag + 10, will be Visible. If I press again the same thumbnail image, what now has red borderColor, the Full Size image will be hidden, and the border will be white.

The code works, but my problem is: I can show and hide each Full Size image ONLY Twice.

**THE IDEA IS THAT THUMBNAILS SHOULD WORK LIKE UIButton with pressed and normal states.**

I don't want to use UIButtons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood truely, you must not write below lines.

```
[self.view addSubview:showFullImage];
```

and

```
[hideFullImage removeFromSuperView];
```

Also you reset tag after hide.

```
[hideFullImage setTag:sender+10];
```

You add view and hide before you call showImage.

Comment: I remove that line which removes the image from superView, and works great. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you forgot to reset your image try this:

```
UIImageView *hideFullImage = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:sender+20];
[hideFullImage removeFromSuperView];
[hideFullImage setTag:sender+10];
hideFullImage.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I tried, but the same situation. I can show/hide once, then again, show/hide, when I try third time, doesn't show the image. I added NSLog to see if that method is called, and Yes, it's called each time when I press. I don't know where is the problem :(